# jQuery server/browser tax and flicker

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, webserver

I have a few of these on a couple pages on a new portal im building and was wondering how taxing it is on the server/client browser to have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#passed_views").load('counter_passed.php');
  }, 500);
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Also, it does seem to flicker on and off in Chrome... is there a better way to activate a listener like this?

Any help - suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: 500 is pretty intense... That's a request every half second for what appears to be a view counter... The question is impossible to answer without knowing what kind of server infrastructure you're working with, but I wouldn't bother going to the server more than once every 30 seconds for something like that. It is essentially a balance between how critical the information is to be up to date, how easy it can be retrieved, and how many people you expect to be requesting it at any given time.

Comment: I'm assuming that since you didn't specify your server setup you're on shared hosting. Your average web host will definitely suffer if you have multiple bits of code like the above and have as little as 25 visitors at a time. But, again, you have given next to no information. Knowing only what you have said, the answer is "it depends."

Comment: Hey, sorry I've not checked this in the last day. We're on a dedicated server so it is 100% dedicated to this web property. At any given time off the bat I'm sure for the first year+ will maybe at maximum be 10-30 people at any given time. Is there a better method for having live data processed that you would maybe recommend/

Comment: Additionally for those counters I've already changed the time that was just for testing. Typically have them set at 10000. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If it's dedicated I wouldn't worry about it too much for 30 users. I don't know the total number of counters that will be in any one page or how complicated of a query it is to retrieve these numbers but it shouldn't be a problem either way, especially if the timer is set to 10000.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script that runs ajax every 60 seconds and typical users have a 1-3 second delay from the time it fired to the time it gets a response back, some users go up to 10 seconds ect. What I would do is verify you got data back from your prior ajax call before sending another request so it doesn't Que up a bunch of requests. That way you could just not even use a set time, just use a loop that calls the script each time it gets a return from the previous call so people with slow times get it say 5 seconds apart and people with faster loads get it 1 second apart.